# Field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ with $\alpha=\sqrt[3]7+2i$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

(1) Prove that $\alpha=\sqrt[3]7+2i$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}.$
(2) Prove that both $\sqrt[3]7, 2i$ are elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.
(3) Compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$.
(4) Find the minimal polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Here is my attempt on each question

1. $x=\sqrt[3]7+2i$
   $x-2i=\sqrt[3]7$
   $(x-2i)^3=7$
   $x^3-12x-7=6ix^2-8i$
   $(x^3-12x-7)^2=(6ix^2-8i)^2$
   $x^6+12x^4-14x^3+48x^2+168x+113=0$
2. Let $\beta=\sqrt[3]7-2i$
   $\alpha+\beta=\sqrt[3]7$
   $\alpha-\beta=4i$
   I tried to use the fact $(\alpha+\beta)^3=7, (\alpha+\beta)^2=-16\in \mathbb{Q}$
   To show $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, but it wasn't successful so far
3. From (2), $\sqrt[3]7, i \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and it's trivial that any new elment of field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ generated by $\alpha$ can be written with {$1, \sqrt[3]7, \sqrt[3]{7^2}, i, \sqrt[3]7i , \sqrt[3]{7^2}i$} and vice versa, i.e. $S=\mathbb{Q}(1, \sqrt[3]7, \sqrt[3]{7^2}, i, \sqrt[3]7i , \sqrt[3]{7^2}i)  = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$
   Also,{$1, \sqrt[3]7, \sqrt[3]{7^2}, i, \sqrt[3]7i , \sqrt[3]{7^2}i$} are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.
   Therefore, $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=6$
4. $p(x)=x^6+12x^4-14x^3+48x^2+168x+113$ from (1) is the minimal polynomial.
   $p(x)$ is a monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. To show it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$,
   reducing mod 3 yields $x^6-2x^3+2$. This factors over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ if and only if
   it has a root in $\mathbb{Z_3}$, but it doesn't have a root.
   Hence, $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z_3}$, so it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Any idea on question 2 or is there anything to fix in other questions?

Comment: Why is $\beta$ in the field?

Comment: Why does $x^6-2x^3+2$ factoring over $\mathbb Z_3$ mean it must have a root? What if it factors as the product of cubics polyonmials or quadratic polynomials?

Comment: In particular, $x^6-2x^3+2=(x^2-2x+2)^3$ modulo $3$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews we don't know if $\beta$ in the field, but it is kinda a congugate of $\alpha$. And if $\sqrt[3]7, 2i \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $\beta$ must be in $\mathbb{Q}$. oh I think 4 is wrong then. I just realized that once we showed $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}$ is finite then it should be equal to deg(f) where f(x) is the minimal polynomial. Hence $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: I mean $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $2:$

Given that: 
$$x^6+12x^4-14x^3+48x^2+168x+113=(x^3-12x-7)^2+(6x^2-8)^2,$$ you have that:

$$\left(\frac{\alpha^3-12\alpha-7}{6\alpha^2-8}\right)^2=-1,$$

at least as long as you can show that $6\alpha^2\neq 8.$

This means that $$\frac{\alpha^3-12\alpha-7}{6\alpha^2-8}=\pm i$$ and hence $i\in\mathbb Q(\alpha)$.

For (3-4): Since $\mathbb Q(i)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]7)\subseteq \mathbb Q(\alpha)$, you have that $[Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]$ must be divisible to $3$ and $2$, and thus be divisible by $6$.

But your polynomial also gives us that $[\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]\leq 6$.

So $\mathbb Q(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=6$, and thus the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ must be degree $6$.

Comment: $\alpha=\sqrt[3]{7}+2i, (\alpha-2i)^3=7, \alpha^3-12\alpha+(8-6\alpha^2)i=7, i=\frac{7-\alpha^3+12\alpha}{8-6\alpha^2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}+2i)$, also $\sqrt[3]{7} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}+2i)$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7}+2i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{7},2i)$ is more likely to come up with.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof of the irreducibility of $f(x)=x^6 +12x^4-14x^3 +48x^2+168x+113$ is not correct. Here’s a way of doing it, though. Over $\Bbb Q(i)$, we have the factorization
$$
f(x)=(x^3-6ix^2-12x+8i-7)(x^3+6ix^2-12x-8i-7)\,,
$$
which can be found by various methods. These cubic polynomials are $\Bbb Q(i)$-irreducible, since their roots are not in $\Bbb Q(i)$, so this is *the* $\Bbb Q(i)$-factorization into irreducibles, unique.

Now assume $f$ had a nontrivial $\Bbb Q$ factorization. This would be a $\Bbb Q(i)$-factorization, and hence the product of two quadratics in the displayed formula. But these are not $\Bbb Q$-polynomials, contradicting our assumption. So $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, @ThomasAndrews .